# How can convert 15000000.00 to 15,000,000 in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

There is a one value 15000000.00  with Numeric datatype in SQL server.

How can i get or convert the value 15000000.00 to 15,000,000?

Comment: You mean you want to display 15,000,000 or actually change it to a string with commas?  I presume you just want to display it this way...in that case, what are you displaying it in?

Comment: The discussion [here](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/113_2009_3_0_0_925917/format-number-with-thousand-separator.htm) may give you an answer.

Comment: Yes, I just want to diaplay the figure 15000000.00 like $15,000,000

Comment: Then how is this a SQL Server question? Presentation is done in the clients.

Answer (score 6):

The database server is the wrong place to do this. Localization should be handled in the presentation layer, not the datastore.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working with the money type, or you want the result to be a money type it could be as simple as:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @money_val, 1) -- you may have to cast to money from int first
```

Check out [this link](http://blog.beyondrelational.com/2009/03/how-to-convert-number-to-comma.html) for a deeper discussion:

Here is an excerpt:

> Comma-formatting is available only for
>   MONEY data types. If you want to
>   comma-format INT, DECIMAL etc, you
>   should cast it to MONEY and do a
>   convert with style flag 1.
>
> DECLARE @m DECIMAL(10,2) SELECT @m =
>   '23456789.25'
>
> SELECT
>       CONVERT(VARCHAR, @m, 1) AS DecimalValue,
>       CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(@m AS MONEY), 1) AS MoneyValue     /*
>   DecimalValue
>   MoneyValue
>
> ---
>
> 23456789.25                    23,456,789.25
>   */

Answer (score 1):

This is not a conversion. 15.000.000,00 (german writing) is the string representation of 15 million. A decimal data type does not store the string, but the value.

All string represenration you see are basically visualizations - in enterprise manager or software according to the settings (locale) when generating the string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to save your numeric data in formats. You can do this when selecting:

`SELECT CONVERT(varchar(12), value, 1) AS formattedvalue FROM table`

The last 1 is a convert style that puts in the . and , signs (depending on your local settings and numeric type).

If you ask me, I wouldn't even let the SQL database server worry about this and format the number in code itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used the following with success

```
SELECT
  Convert(VARCHAR, Cast(100000.01 AS MONEY), 1) Amount
```

Results:
Amount
-----------------------------
100,000.01